# MySQL, PHP: Check Race condition before update

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column (lets call it A) in my table called status which I update based on user action. The column A holds status as integers. I write 1 to the field A when user requests for the status and 2 where user confirms( by hitting a confirm button on the UI) having read the value(code). However I have a condition where if any of the user has already confirmed the value then I need to prevent updating the table and instead report an error to the user saying "This Value has already been confirmed".

Currently in my PHP code to prevent more than one user from updating the value, I read(Step 1) from the table the value of A and only if the value is not 2 then I immediately write to the table updating the value(Step 2).

```
$status = $code->getStatus($id); //Step1
if($status!=2) {
  $code->updateStatus($id); //Step 2
}else{
  echo "This value has already been confirmed";
}
```

However my concern is what if another request to confirm value(and hence update value to 2) came in when the first request was yet to execute Step 2 and the new request had already executed Step 1.  Request 2 having executed Step 1 will return $status as 1 and hence move to executing Step 2 causing an overwrite. How do I prevent this either in PHP or MYSQL given I will have numerous users?

Comment: FYI 0 = false 1 = true. Use conventions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

Comment: If I understand your senario correctly. Wont the result of this be that one of the 2 requests updated the status to 2. In which case is it actually an issue that is worth worrying about.

Comment: @nerdlyist have a reason why I use 1,2. This is because in my actual program I have multiple states for this variable viz 1,2,3,4. I just made it short for me to explain here.

Comment: You simplified too much then because now even the provided answer with the most upvotes is not helpful to you. Revise your question so we know what you are doing with this status.

Comment: @nerdlyist you are right. Let me first try using JiriHrazdil 's answer and see where I get and then add more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not check status value in UPDATE query?

```
UPDATE `table` SET `status` = 2 WHERE `id` = 123 AND `status` = 1
```

And then check for number of affected rows - if it is greater than zero, update was perfomed successfully. If not, there are two possible causes: `id` was not found or `status` was not 1.